# Aggregate using first pair as seed

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

Is there any way to aggregate (fold) this a sequence

```
{ a, b, c, d }
```

with a function `f(x,y)` So that I end up with `f(f(f(a,b),c),d)`

```
result = f(a,b)
result = f(result, c)
result = f(result, d)
```

Currently I do this (assume the list length is >= 2):

```
var seed = f(list[0], list[1]);
var result = list.Skip(2).Aggregate(seed, f);
```

Can I express the same thing in a single expression?

EDIT: Assume the type of the result of `f` is *not* the same as the element type, and there is no good "zero element" for `f`, i.e. a good seed value such that `f(0, a) = a`. Examples of operations with zero elements are addition (zero element=`0`), multiplication (zero element=`1`), list concatenation (zero element=`[]`).

An example of an operation with no good zero element is a an average, i.e.

```
result = avg(a,b)
result = avg(result, c)
result = avg(result, d)
```

The only valid seeds for this fold are either `avg(a,a)` or `avg(a,b)`. So for the function `avg` and the input sequence `{a, b, c, d}` I'd like `result = avg(avg(avg(a,b),c),d)`

Comment: maybe just list.Skip(2).Aggregate(f(list[0], list[1]), f); helps you?

Comment: it's just `list.Aggregate(f)`

Comment: Dmytro that would be my two lines in a single line yes, but hardly any more elegant. Xi: see my edit, the result type is not the same as the element type.

Answer (score 5):

`Aggregate` already applies the aggregation function to the first pair so you shouldn't need to separate those:

```
var result = list.Aggregate((a,b) => f(a,b));
```

However, if the accumulating value has a different type than the collection elements then you can't use the overload above (which is probably why you're asking this question). You could start off with a seed value of "zero" that allows you to start with the first element only, and eliminates the need for `Skip`:

```
Func<int, string, int> f = (a, b) => a + b.Length;
var list = new[] { "1", "12", "123", "1234" };
var seed = 0;
var result = list.Aggregate(seed, (a, b) => f(a, b));
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any seed in this case, try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload of Aggregate function:

```
var result = list.Aggregate((a,b)=>f(a,b));
```